# is there anybody out there still using Vector(instead of Collections.synchronizedList(List list)/CopyOnWriteArrayList)?

Tags: java, collections, vector, synchronization, arraylist

I wonder why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986296/what-are-the-differences-between-arraylist-and-vector) question still exists in 2011,J2SE 1.2 was released in Dec 98 with Collections framework.is there anybody out there still using Vector(unless you are writing client for interface that returns Vector)?

Comment: You still see questions popping up on SO that use `Vector`. It makes me cry.

Comment: Questions about Vector, Hashtable and Enumeration sadly still appear all of the time, although all three of them have been semi-deprecated for years. Still, this is **not a real question**

Comment: Old JDK classes never die, they just slowly fade away.

Comment: Don't forget about Java ME and different big old projects.

Answer (score 2):

Java 5.0 introduce the concurrency collections in 2004, and many people don't appear to be using these instead of Collections.synchronizedList().  They are not a direct replacement, sometimes it is better to use the JDK 1.2 or 5.0 collections but it surprised me how often people don't make good use of them.

Comment: thanks for mentioning Concurrent collections classes.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Vector or Hashtable in many years now.

Answer (score 0):

Legacy collection classes such as `Vector` and `Hashtable` still exist because Sun (and now Oracle) always deemed it extremely important to keep Java backwards compatible. They never remove old stuff from the standard Java API, because that would break old programs.

The real question should be: Why did Sun (or Oracle) not make the legacy collection classes deprecated?

There isn't a clear technical reason why the old classes are not deprecated. Probably this is because other parts of the API are still using those legacy classes and Sun / Oracle don't want to bother users too much with deprecation warnings during compilation.

Anyway, never use those legacy classes unless you really have to (for example because you're dealing with an old API).

Answer (score 0):

I use Vector frequently mostly with Swing.  I have a lot of applications that use classes like DefaultTableModel that are really simple to use if you have data in a Vector.  There are ways around this, but I like to keep simple as it does not hinder performance.

However, any other time I need a list I do not use Vector.