# ArrayList vs Vector - other advantages than thread-safety and performance?

Tags: java, vector, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between ArrayList and Vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986296/what-are-the-differences-between-arraylist-and-vector)

If I want to store some objects in a data collection and I have to choose between an ArrayList or a Vector, what are the main differences? I think vector are thread-safe and therefore have a performance penalty. Are there any other reasons to prefer on of the data containers?

Comment: Have you had a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986296/what-are-the-differences-between-arraylist-and-vector)?

Comment: About the limits of Vector concerning syncronization: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1386288/870122

Comment: Just as an aside, the only time I'd use `Vector` is when wanting to use a J2SE constructor or method that accepts a `Vector`  (the Swing API is polluted with them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vector is a very old class from before the introduction of the Collections framework, therefore its API is polluted with many legacy methods that duplicate the methods from the `Collection` and `List` interface.

I'd generally avoid using it unless you have to because another API you're using demands it.

Answer (score 3):

In short main difference between Vector and ArrayList is that Vector is synchronized while ArrayList is not. So, if multiple threads access an ArrayList concurrently then we must externally synchronize the block of code which modifies the list either structurally or simply modifies an element. Structural modification means addition or deletion of element(s) from the list. Setting the value of an existing element is not a structural modification.
These two url's will be helpful to you. http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/difference-vector-vs-arraylist-in-java.html and
http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/05/difference-between-vector-and-arraylist.html

Answer (score 3):

You have said it yourself. All the methods in Vector are painfully synchronized. Synchronization over a collection if required can be applied outside the class, preferably on case by case basis.

One more subtle difference between ArrayList and Vector is that you can control how the Vector can grow. Whereas in Arraylist, the size of internal array always doubles