# Removing all zeros from an array list?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, arraylist

So i currently have :

```
List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
String thisLine = reader.readLine();

while (thisLine != null) {
    lineList.add(thisLine);
    thisLine = reader.readLine();
}
System.out.println(lineList);
```

Which basically is reading a text file and returning the numbers in the text file. 
The output im getting is `[0  6  13  0  0  75  33  0  0  0  4  29  21  0  86  0  32  66  0  0]`
which seems to be correct. However what I have to do is remove all the zeros without creating a new array. But will i have to convert this string `arraylist` to an integer array list to be able to do so? How could I only remove the zeros?
Thanks!

Comment: whether there is only one integer per line ?

Comment: Won't looping around the `lineList` once more solve your problem with `lineList.remove()` ?

Comment: removing "0" or 0 is the same

Comment: See also [Remove all zeros from array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8777217/456814).

Answer (score 4):

use [**removeAll()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) method to remove all zeros from an ArrayList...

> lineList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(0));

Answer (score 3):

You just need to modify your while loop like this:

```
 while (thisLine != null) {
       if(!thisLine.trim().equals("0")) {
           lineList.add(thisLine);
       }
        thisLine = reader.readLine();
    }
```

EDIT:

As per your input above code will not work as you are getting everything in a single line. You should use a Scanner to read it like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(<your file path>));
 List<Integer> lineList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(s.hasNextInt()){
    int i = s.nextInt();
     if(i!=0) {
         lineList.add(i);
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like this solution because it avoids adding the 0's in the first place.

Comment: I replaced my while loop with it yet it when i output lineList it still gives me the list with the zeros in it, any idea why?

Comment: whats the content in the file?

Comment: exactly this "0  6  13  0  0  75  33  0  0  0  4  29  21  0  86  0  32  66  0  0"

Comment: ahhh it worked! thanks so much! Stayed up all night trying to troubleshoot this program.

Answer (score 0):

I'd to it in the while loop:

```
while (thisLine != null) {
    if(!thisLine.equals("0"){
        lineList.add(thisLine);
    }
    thisLine = reader.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this would be sufficient ?

```
for(Iterator<String> it=lineList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String str = it.next();
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
        it.remove();   
    }
}
```