# How to remove zeros from int array?

Tags: java, arrays, int

This is my array:  `int[] test= new int[] {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`

Now I need to remove all the zeros from this array so it will display like this:  **Output : {1,1}**

I tried this code from this [link-StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777217/remove-all-zeros-from-array) but didn't work for me.

```
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        if (test[i] != 0)
            test[j++] = test[i];
    }
    int[] newArray = new int[j];
    System.arraycopy(test, 0, newArray, 0, j);
    return newArray;
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: It wont remove 0 from it simply returns same.

Comment: I've just tried you code and it works fine! newArray = {1,1}

Comment: I just use logcat before and after but getting same here.

Comment: this code is correct, so, please add the complete code of this method and how you pass arguments to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you insist to work with array you can use this :

```
int n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    if (test[i] != 0)
        n++;
}

int[] newArray = new int[n];
int j=0;

for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    if (test[i] != 0)
       { 
         newArray[j]=test[i]; 
         j++;
       }
}

return newArray;
```

---

Or Try to use list :

```
List<Integer> list_result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for( int i=0;  i<test.length;  i++ )
{
    if (test[i] != 0)
        list_result.add(test[i]);
}
return list_result;
```

to parse list :

```
for( int i=0;  i<list_result.size();  i++ )
{
        system.out.pintln((Integer)list_result.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `List` instead. Then you can just do `list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(0));`. Arrays are far harder to use for this kind of thing.

Example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4));
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(0));
System.out.println(list);
```

Output: [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: Hi thanks for your time, this code didn't work it shows **cannot invoke removeAll(set<Integer>on array type of int[])** :(

Comment: No, it won't work on an array. You need to use `List<Integer>` instead of `int[]`. It's just my advice. Wait a few minutes and somebody will post an answer using `int[]`, but I wouldn't recommend doing it that way.

Comment: yeah got but i need to add that integers dynamically so i used int[], while running program i used like this to add int into array `test = new int[] { Count1, Count2, Count3,`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Java, but if there is a Underscore or Lo-dash library you can use; then you can employ .filter functionality;

This code is from Swift;

```
var numbers = [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
numbers = numbers.filter({ $0 != 0 })  // returns [1,1]
```