# how does an ArrayList compare to a dynamic array

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist

Is an `ArrayList` is just the interface for a dynamic array? Or are they the same thing?

like: `ArrayList` corresponds to dynamic array, `HashMap` corresponds to `Map` ?

except I don't see any Java API for something like a *dynamic array*, unless it is `ArrayList`?

Comment: "like: ArrayList corresponds to Map, dynamic array corresponds to HashMap?" No, neither parts of that make any real sense; maps and arrays are two separate data structures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In short.
 A longer explanation is that an `ArrayList` is a collection that uses arrays for storage, rather than a linked list, doubly linked list or similar. This means that it gives all the benefits of using an Array, whilst Java looks after the mechanics of sizing the Array for you (dynamically).

I seem to remember that the initial array is created with a default maximum size (which can be specified by the user). Should the collection run out of space, then a larger array is created and the contents of the original array copied into the new one. The increment in size is set to prevent this happening too often, as the operation is fairly costly.

Java also offers the `Vector` collection which is similar, but is also thread safe, see: [What are the differences between ArrayList and Vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986296/what-are-the-differences-between-arraylist-and-vector).

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is the resizable-array implementation of the `List` interface.
So that's probably what you are looking for if you need a dynamic array.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is not a dynamic array, it's not an array type dynamic or not, it's just one of the implementations of the `List` interface. Understand the difference between [classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html) and [interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). On the other hand [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) are container objects with the fixed size.

Comment: There's a difference between the abstract data type "dynamic array" and the weird generic built-in type `T[]` ("array of `T`").

Answer (score 1):

If in the **dynamic sense** you mean an array which can change in size then a `List` is an interface for a dynamic array. It is named `ArrayList` because it uses an array internally that's all.

Your analogy does not fit in the java collections framework since you can say that an `ArrayList` is a dynamic array but `Map` (or `HashMap` for that matter) does not have a "primitive" counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

If by 'dynamic array' you mean an array in C++, then all arrays in Java are dynamic and stored on heap. `ArrayList` is a resizable wrapper for it. It also provides simple consistency checks - i.e. that you don't modify your array from outside during iteration.