# Load database values to Vector

Tags: java, database, vector

we have a database and in this database there is one table "content" and 3 columns "id", "movie_name", "movie_category".

We want to load this values to Vector and show it but there is a problem that we just get "null" value.

How can we fix this ?

```
import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.ResultSet;  
import java.sql.Statement; 
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Data extends JPanel{

         Connection connection = null;  
         ResultSet resultSet = null;  
         Statement statement = null;  

         static Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
         public String vString;

         public String database(){
             try 
             {  
                 Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
                 connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src//movies.db");  
                 statement = connection.createStatement();  
                 resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id, movie_name, movie_category FROM content");

                 Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
                 columnNames.add("id");
                 columnNames.add("movie_name");
                 columnNames.add("movie_category");

                 while (resultSet.next()) 
                 {  
                     Vector<String> vString = new Vector<String>();

                     vString.addElement(resultSet.getString("id"));
                     vString.addElement(resultSet.getString("movie_name"));
                     vString.addElement(resultSet.getString("movie_category"));


                     data.add(vString);




                 }  
             } //try
             catch (Exception e) 
             {  
                 e.printStackTrace();  
             }
             finally 
             {  
                 try 
                 {  
                     resultSet.close();  
                     statement.close();  
                     connection.close();  
                 } 
                 catch (Exception e) 
                 {  
                     e.printStackTrace();  
                 }  
             }
            return vString;  
         }


public static void main(String[] args) {


    Data d = new Data();
    System.out.print(d.database());

}

}
```

Comment: Please post the **relevant** part of the code here.

Comment: for good understanding i post whole of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you declared instance variable `vString` but you never assign anything to it, so it stays (auto)initialized with `null`. Inside the while loop you declare a local varibale `vString` and it is used for storing data retrieved from database. After while loop ends, local varibale `vString`  is not more. In `main` method you print the result of `database()` method what is `null` stored in the instance variable `vString`.
Your problem is known as [Variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

1. Change `System.out.print(d.database())` to `System.out.print(d.data)`
2. Delete declaration `public String vString`
3. Make `database()` method return `void`

Repaired code:

```
public class Data extends JPanel{

     Connection connection = null;  
     ResultSet resultSet = null;  
     Statement statement = null;  

     static Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

     public void database(){
         try 
         {  
             Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
             connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src//movies.db");  
             statement = connection.createStatement();  
             resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id, movie_name, movie_category FROM content");

             Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
             columnNames.add("id");
             columnNames.add("movie_name");
             columnNames.add("movie_category");

             while (resultSet.next()) 
             {  
                 Vector<String> vString = new Vector<String>();

                 vString.addElement(resultSet.getString("id"));
                 vString.addElement(resultSet.getString("movie_name"));
                 vString.addElement(resultSet.getString("movie_category"));

                 data.add(vString);
             }  
         } //try
         catch (Exception e) 
         {  
             e.printStackTrace();  
         }
         finally 
         {  
             try 
             {  
                 resultSet.close();  
                 statement.close();  
                 connection.close();  
             } 
             catch (Exception e) 
             {  
                 e.printStackTrace();  
             }  
         }
     }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Data d = new Data();
    d.database();
    System.out.print(d.data);
}
```

Comment: we delete the outer vString but when we try to return inner vString it is also occurs a problem. can you modify that part of the code ?

Comment: i changed System.out.print(d.data()); with System.out.print(d.data); because there is no data() method but i still get the same result

Comment: Are you sure there are any data in database?

Comment: yes i have a sqlite database named "movies.db" and it has values in it

Comment: i trieed to add a value to vector manually vString.addElement("a"); it still shows [] as a result

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to call d.database() within main method.

Comment: You're welcome. And for the future consider using `ArrayList` instead of `Vector` ([differences-between-arraylist-and-vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986296/what-are-the-differences-between-arraylist-and-vector))

Comment: it is my homework and my teacher told us "i strongly suggest you using vector" that is why i try to use vector