# ArrayLists, References, & Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, vector

I'm working on a project where I need to use recursion, and arraylists/vectors to solve a 3-satisfiability instance.  The task is to select a sub-set of integers, such that each set denoted below contains one or more elements of the sub-set.  The constraint being that a number, i & its opposite, -i, cannot both be in the sub-set.

```
Vector<Vector<Integer>> matrix = new Vector<Vector<Integer>>();
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    matrix.add(new Vector<Integer>());
}
```

the 2-dimensional vector/arraylist is then filled with numbers, for example:

```
1, -2, 3
-1, 2, 4
2, -3, 4
-1, -2, -3

if(startRec(matrix)
{
   //solution is found
}
else
{ 
   //no solution is possible
}


private boolean startRec(Vector<Vector<Integer>> matrix)
{  // I'm using trial and error to find a solution to the above problem.  So in the below, matrix.get(0).get(i) is selected as part of a possibly correct set.  
    boolean success=false;
    if(stagen(matrix.get(0).get(0), matrix))
    {
        success=true;
    }
    else if(stagen(matrix.get(0).get(1),matrix))
    {
        success=true;
    }
    else if(stagen(matrix.get(0).get(2),matrix))
    {
        success=true;
    }

    return success;
}
private boolean stagen(int input, Vector<Vector<Integer>> matrix)
{
   removei(input, matrix) // this removes all Vector<Integer> that contain i.  Those sets are considered satisfied, and no longer need to be addressed.
   removenegative(input,matrix) // this removes all integers that are -input.  Since i and -i cannot both be selected, I'm removing the -input. 
//So if a set contained three ints, one of which was -input, it now contains 2.
    boolean success=false;
    if(stagen(matrix.get(0).get(0), matrix)) // since the original matrix.get(0) contained input, it was removed in removei(input,matrix), thus this is a one below the one called previously.
    {
        success=true;
    }
    else if(stagen(matrix.get(0).get(1),matrix))
    {
        success=true;
    }
    else if(stagen(matrix.get(0).get(2),matrix))
    {
        success=true;
    }

    return success;
}
```

I've removed the out of range checks, to make it more readable.  But the process I'm confident is going on is this:

```
 1, -2, 3   //1 is selected in the second line of startRec
-1, 2, 4
2, -3, 4
-1, -2, -3

 //1, -2, 3 line is removed from consideration by method removei() as 1 has been selected
 2, 4       // -1 has been removed as both 1,-1 cannot be selected.
2, -3, 4
-2, -3     // -1 removed.

 2, 4       now 2 is the first number, so 2 is selected.
-2, 3, 4   
-2, -3 

//2, 4     removed via removei method.
3, 4       //-2 is removed, because 2 has been selected.
-3         //-2removed.

3, 4    //Now 3 is selected.
-3

//3, 4  line removed as it has been satisfied.
_____   //There's now an empty set here as -3 was deleted 
//false is returned by stagen.
```

The program returns to the stagen which selected 3, and it now ideally now select 4 as the next letter.  But I deleted that whole row.

Is there a way to do this without creating an unknown number of vectors?

2ndly, is there a significant difference between arraylists & vectors?  I've been using arraylists, exclusively, but the project suggests vectors.

Comment: Do you even know what recursion is?

Comment: No significant difference between ArrayList & Vector, though in real life scenarios I'd recommend ArrayList. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986296/what-are-the-differences-between-arraylist-and-vector for details on the minor differences

Comment: I don't understand how you intend to manipulate this through recursion, or what the problem is. Can you provide a rough example?

Comment: "But I want the original to still exist unaltered.

Is there a way to do this without creating an unknown number of vectors?" No.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question is incoherent. However I'll elaborate on the differences between Vector and Arraylist:

- If multiple threads access an ArrayList concurrently then you need to externally synchronize the block of code which **modifies** the list.
- Internally, both of them use an array to maintain the data structure. If running out of space, ArrayList increases its size by 50% while Vector doubles its size.

Refer [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077425/java-se/vector-or-arraylist-which-is-better.html) thread for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Vector is also much slower than Arraylist because of its synchronization requirements.