# Why is the following Vector code broken exactly?

Tags: java, synchronization

follows from  :
  [Synchronization in Vectors in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144851/synchronization-in-vectors-in-java)

Why is the below code broken as far as synchronization is considered?
Is the vector class not synchronized on its own object (`this`)?

```
  // BROKEN CODE, needs external synchronization
 // only add an element if the vector is empty
     if(vector.isEmpty())
         vector.add(anElement);
```

UPDATE:

Going by the answers(from jon Skeet and Pshemo) below, doesn't it render vectors practically useless(that we have arraylist)?

Because we need to synchronise manually anyway for any practical use.
If yes, what is stopping Java from marking vector deprecated atleast?

Comment: @fge : Knowledge never hurts :P

Comment: Regarding your update: If I remember correctly synchronization of single operations saves us from inconsistent state for instance caused by race. With synchronization when we invoke `add(foo)` and `add(bar)` we are sure that both methods will be executed correctly without worrying about possible problems when we will try to place one element while inner array used by vector will need to be resized to store more elements and new element will be placed in old array for instance right before it will be replaced by new array storing all elements.

Comment: Yes, Vector is practically useless.  That said, my understanding is that Java doesn't deprecate things if they aren't planned to be deleted, and too much legacy code depends on Vector to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the vector class not synchronized on its own object (this)?

Yes, but only for each individual operation.

Here we have two operations:

```
if (vector.isEmpty())
    vector.add(anElement);
```

It's possible that between the check of `isempty` and the `add` call, a different thread could add an item. The fix is to add synchronization over the *combined* operation:

```
synchronized (vector) {
    if (vector.isEmpty()) {
        vector.add(anElement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

State of `vector` can change between `if(vector.isEmpty())` test and `vector.add(anElement);` method. Other thread can simply add some element between these actions.

We want to add `anElement` to vector only if it is empty. But with current code it is possible that

```
            Thread A       |            Thread B
---------------------------+---------------------------
take vector lock           |
check if vector is empty   |
release vector lock        |
                           | take vector lock
                           | add `otherElement`
                           | release vector lock
take vector lock           |
add `anElement`            |
release vector lock        |
```

so as you see single operations are thread safe, but entire transaction is not.